# Where is rbenv installed on mac?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I'm trying to uninstall rbenv on my mac but can't figure out where it's installed. I'm stuck at step 2 on https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv#uninstalling-rbenv. I think I used homebrew to install rbenv.

Comment: Have you checked: ~/.rbenv ?

Comment: I you used homebrew you can uninstall it with `brew uninstall rbenv`. You can see where a keg (a homebrew package) is installed by `brew info rbenv`.

Comment: @TomFast that is correct.

Comment: @max yes but I also had to rm -rf the rbenv root directory as per step number 2 in the link I posed in the question. But both of your answers were useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note the quote in the command of Step 2 is a backtick(on keyboard, it is the key right ubove tab key), not a quotation sign.

```
`rbenv root`  # this command will return the root directory where rbenv installed.
rm -rf `rbenv root`  # this will uninstall rbenv completed.
```